# How to create a Django superuser if it doesn't exist non-interactively?

Tags: python, django, bash, django-users

I want to automate creation of Django users via a Bash script. I found this snippet which almost suits my needs:

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')" |\
    python manage.py shell
```

How can I modify it so that it's a nop if the user already exists?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Using `manage.py shell`

You can use the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) methods to check if a user exists, and then create it if it doesn't. Also, it may be easier to put the code in a heredoc:

```
cat <<EOF | python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()  # get the currently active user model,

User.objects.filter(username='admin').exists() or \
    User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')
EOF
```

#### Using a custom management command

Another, more maintainable option is to add a custom [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) for your Django app. Adapting the example from the docs, edit `yourapp/management/commands/ensure_adminuser.py` to look like this:

```
import os
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Creates an admin user non-interactively if it doesn't exist"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--username', help="Admin's username")
        parser.add_argument('--email', help="Admin's email")
        parser.add_argument('--password', help="Admin's password")
        parser.add_argument('--no-input', help="Read options from the environment",
                            action='store_true')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        User = get_user_model()

        if options['no_input']:
            options['username'] = os.environ['DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME']
            options['email'] = os.environ['DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL']
            options['password'] = os.environ['DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD']

        if not User.objects.filter(username=options['username']).exists():
            User.objects.create_superuser(username=options['username'],
                                          email=options['email'],
                                          password=options['password'])
```

Then you can call the new custom command from your Bash script like this:

```
python manage.py ensure_adminuser --username=admin \
    --email=admin@example.com \
    --password=pass
```

Comment: this answer is complete, helped me a lot. Thx :)

Answer (score 3):

This bash function does the trick, even if you have a custom user model in your app:

```
create-superuser () {
    local username="$1"
    local email="$2"
    local password="$3"
    cat <<EOF | python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

if not User.objects.filter(username="$username").exists():
    User.objects.create_superuser("$username", "$email", "$password")
else:
    print('User "{}" exists already, not created'.format("$username"))
EOF
}
```

Credits to Eugene Yarmash for the original idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). If it exists it will do nothing, else it will create one.

You'd have to set the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` to `True` manually

Answer (score -2):

For django version greater than 3, create two environment variables named DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME and DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD and optionally DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL with desired values with commands in bash file. Then run createsuperuser command inside bash. Here is sample bash script:

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=pass
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@example.com
python manage.py createsuperuser --no-input
```

Original document is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser).

Comment: This one errors out if the user already exists, thus not directly solving the problem, unless you add additional error-handling